# Testing different implementations of malloc()

Tags: c, memory-management, benchmarking

Can you help me verify my test result? I'm testing different `malloc()` implementations with a small program that allocates gigabytes many times:

```
int main(int agrc, char **argv) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        void *p = malloc(1024 * 1024 * 1024);
        free(p);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

If I run it and time it, then it takes 5 seconds:

> ```
> $ time ./gig 
>
> real  0m5.140s
> user  0m0.384s
> sys   0m4.752s
> ```

Now I try my custom `malloc()` with exactly the same program and it seems unreasonable faster.

> ```
> $ time ./gb_quickfit
>
> real  0m0.045s
> user  0m0.044s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```

Why is the custom `malloc()` so much faster? I used the "quick `malloc()`" algorithm.

```
void *malloc_quick(size_t nbytes) /* number of bytes of memory to allocate */
{
    Header *moreroce(unsigned);
    int index, i;
    index = qindex(nbytes);

    /* 
     * Use another strategy for too large allocations. We want the allocation
     * to be quick, so use malloc_first().
     */

    if (index >= NRQUICKLISTS) {
        return malloc_first(nbytes);
    }

    /* Initialize the quick fit lists if this is the first run. */
    if (first_run) {
        for (i = 0; i < NRQUICKLISTS; ++i) {
            quick_fit_lists[i] = NULL;
        }
        first_run = false;
    }


    /*
     * If the quick fit list pointer is NULL, then there are no free memory
     * blocks present, so we will have to create some before continuing.
     */

    if (quick_fit_lists[index] == NULL) {
        Header* new_quick_fit_list = init_quick_fit_list(index);
        if (new_quick_fit_list == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        } else {
            quick_fit_lists[index] = new_quick_fit_list;
        }
    }


    /*
     * Now that we know there is at least one free quick fit memory block,
     * let's use return that and also update the quick fit list pointer so that
     * it points to the next in the list.
     */

    void* pointer_to_return = (void *)(quick_fit_lists[index] + 1);
    quick_fit_lists[index] = quick_fit_lists[index]->s.ptr;
   /* printf("Time taken %d seconds %d milliseconds", msec/1000, msec%1000);*/
    return pointer_to_return;
}
```

I'm sure there is a catch because I don't have much experience in this detailed level of C. Why are the results so different? Does the system `malloc()` only have one algorithm?

Can I be sure that the test is correct? If I run Valgrind with the test, it reports no error . I try again run the test, check with Valgrind that the test doesn't generate error with Valgrind and get the result again

```
$ time ./gb_quickfit 

real    0m0.759s
user    0m0.584s
sys 0m0.172s
dac@dac-Latitude-E7450:~/ClionProjects/omalloc/openmalloc/overhead$ time ./a.out 

real    0m0.826s
user    0m0.644s
sys 0m0.180s
```

Now the result is more reasonable, my custom `malloc` is only slightly faster. The reason I got so large difference first time might have been of errors in the test allocating too much. The second test looks like:

```
/* returns an array of arrays of char*, all of which NULL */
char ***alloc_matrix(unsigned rows, unsigned columns) {
    char ***matrix = malloc(rows * sizeof(char **));
    unsigned row = 0;
    unsigned column = 0;
    if (!matrix) abort();

    for (row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        matrix[row] = calloc(columns, sizeof(char *));
        if (!matrix[row]) abort();
        for (column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
            matrix[row][column] = NULL;
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}

/* deallocates an array of arrays of char*, calling free() on each */
void free_matrix(char ***matrix, unsigned rows, unsigned columns) {
    unsigned row = 0;
    unsigned column = 0;
    for (row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
            /*    printf("column %d row %d\n", column, row);*/
            free(matrix[row][column]);
        }
        free(matrix[row]);
    }
    free(matrix);
}


int main(int agrc, char **argv) {
    /* int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        void *p = malloc(1024 * 1024 * 1024);
        free(p);
    }*/
    int x = 10000;
    char *** matrix = alloc_matrix(x, x);
    free_matrix(matrix, x, x);
    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very possible that the memory is not really being allocated in RAM, but is in the virtual address space. I couldn't guess why your implementation causes this, but if you keep the memory allocated and sleep, you may find (assuming your on Linux, I don't know about Windows) that the memory is allocated but not backed by anything till you use it, due to the size.